# Division of a Panel by a Series

Tags: pandas

I have a panel,

```
In [14]: print electr 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 35 (items) x 6 (major_axis) x 10 (minor_axis)
Items axis: AN to WB
Major_axis axis: Coal to Total Renewable Energy Sources
Minor_axis axis: 2003-01-31 00:00:00 to 2013-01-31 00:00:00
```

What I'd like to do is normalize the values to the sum (along the *major_axis*) at the first timestep, i.e., I'd like to do

```
normed = electr / electr.sum(axis=1).ix[0]
```

However, this gives rise to the error **ValueError: Simple arithmetic with Panel can only be done with scalar values**.

My question:  Which would be the canonical way to do this operation?

Comment: Does the following work: `normed = electr / electr.sum(axis=1).ix[0].values.max()`?

Comment: yes, it works, but is not what I need ;)  I want to normalize each *item* individually, so simply taking the `max()` won't do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `Panel.apply` (requires 0.14.0), see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#applying-with-a-panel.

```
In [8]: p = Panel(np.arange(3*4*5).reshape(3,4,5),items=['ItemA','ItemB','ItemC'],major_axis=date_range('20130101',periods=4),minor_axis=list('ABCDE'))

In [9]: p
Out[9]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 4 (major_axis) x 5 (minor_axis)
Items axis: ItemA to ItemC
Major_axis axis: 2013-01-01 00:00:00 to 2013-01-04 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: A to E

In [10]: d = p.sum(axis=1).ix[0]

In [11]: d
Out[11]: 
ItemA     30
ItemB    110
ItemC    190
Name: A, dtype: int64

In [12]: p.iloc[0]
Out[12]: 
             A   B   C   D   E
2013-01-01   0   1   2   3   4
2013-01-02   5   6   7   8   9
2013-01-03  10  11  12  13  14
2013-01-04  15  16  17  18  19

In [13]: p.apply(lambda x: x/d,axis=0).iloc[0]
Out[13]: 
                   A         B         C         D         E
2013-01-01  0.000000  0.033333  0.066667  0.100000  0.133333
2013-01-02  0.166667  0.200000  0.233333  0.266667  0.300000
2013-01-03  0.333333  0.366667  0.400000  0.433333  0.466667
2013-01-04  0.500000  0.533333  0.566667  0.600000  0.633333
```